# Trying to use random number generator in a coin flip program in C

Tags: c, loops, random, coin-flipping

Hello i'm trying to create a program where it counts the number of heads and tails in a coin flip simulator based on the number of coin flips the user inputs. The issue with this is that when i'm trying to count the number of heads and tails then increment them, it gives me just a random number and not within the range of flips given.

This is a sample output of my error

```
Coin Flip Simulator
How many times do you want to flip the coin? 10
Number of heads: 1804289393
Number of tails: 846930886
```

Instead I want it to count it like this:

```
Coin Flip Simulator
How many times do you want to flip the coin? 10
Number of heads: 7
Number of tails: 3
```

Here's the program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "getdouble.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Coin Flip Simulator\n");
  printf("How many times do you want to flip the coin? ");
  int numFlip = getdouble();
  if(numFlip == 0 || numFlip < 0) {
    printf("Error: Please enter an integer greater than or equal to 1.\n");
  }
  int i = 0;
  int numHead = rand();
  int numTails = rand();
  for (i = 0; i < numFlip; i++) {
    
    if(numFlip%2 == 0) {
      numHead++;
    }
    else {
      numTails++;
    }
  }
  printf("Number of heads: %d\n", numHead);
  printf("Number of tails: %d\n", numTails);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions, it's my first time trying to use the random number generator.

Comment: `int numHead = rand();` and `int numTails = rand();` initialize your counters to random values. Seems like they should probably start at 0 instead. Any call to `rand()` should be inside the loop and test that for odd or even.

Comment: At some point, you'll need to seed the pseudo-random number generator, or use a better, self-seeding PRNG.  With `rand()`, the seeding function is `srand()`.  It's also curious that you use a function `getdouble()` to read an integer — that sounds like a type mismatch.

Comment: Is this a Monte Carlo Viloria simulation?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use an unsigned integer type for `numFlip`.  The main issue is that you need to initialize `numHead` (sic) and `numTails`.  You want to use `srand()` to seed the random number generate otherwise the result is deterministic.  As you only have two options just record number of heads and determine the tails after the fact:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    printf("Coin Flip Simulator\n");
    printf("How many times do you want to flip the coin? ");
    unsigned numFlip;
    if(scanf("%u", &numFlip) != 1) {
        printf("numFlip failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    unsigned numHeads = 0;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < numFlip; i++)
        numHeads += (rand() % 2); // removed ! when @Fe2O3 wasn't looking :-)
    unsigned numTails = numFlip - numHeads;
    printf("Number of heads: %u\n", numHeads);
    printf("Number of tails: %u\n", numTails);
}
```

and example output:

```
Coin Flip Simulator
How many times do you want to flip the coin? 10
Number of heads: 2
Number of tails: 8
```

Comment: UV for the comment in the code... I've bookmarked this Q to keep an eye on you... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 I will strike one day when you least expect it :-)

Comment: Bad advice at the end, the distribution of of `rand() % numFlip` would (ideally) be uniform, while the distribution of #heads is binomial. The modulo method will give too many low and high values, not enough around the mean. Also, if you went with the modulo operator it should be `rand() % (numFlip + 1)` so you can get both 0 and `numFlip` as possible answers.

Comment: @pjs Sorry, I don't understand what you are telling me, but happy to drop that suggestion.

Comment: @AllanWind I’m saying that the number of heads with 10 independent tosses of a fair coin (p{heads} == 1/2) follows a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Plugging those values into a [binomial calculator](https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~mbognar/applets/bin.html) shows that 5 heads is the most likely count, beating 4 or 6 by a slight amount but beating 0, 1, 9, or 10 by a large margin. The results are quite different from a uniform distribution, which the `rand() % 11` approach would approximate (subject to modulo bias and the poor quality of rand()).

Comment: @pjs Thanks for taking the time to spell that out for me.